# How to display the last post of a facebook page on my webpage

Tags: facebook-fql

I've got a facebook page which is publicly accessible. On my website I'd like to display the last post made by this page.

I made a script which uses the facebook php-api and FQL to retrieve the events from the page. But I just can't figure out how to construct a FQL which displays the latest posts from my page. I've seen the stream table and thought I should use it like this:

```
SELECT created_time, 
       likes, message, post_id, share_count, type
FROM 
       stream 
WHERE 
       actor_id = {$page}
LIMIT 5
```

But that results in the fact I need a Starred/Indexable column. Fair enough, but I can't figure out which starred column to use.

Anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use: `source_id` instead of `actor_id`